# a gui/program that runs even during the login screen in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I want to make a program that runs before the user even logs on and the gui is shown in the login screen like this:[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can have a GUI coming up on top of the windows login screen. And neither can you have a GUI program running if no user has logged in to windows OS

Comment: Actually [**this guy**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3143055/3740093) found a way to run a C# GUI application on the Winlogon Desktop. However it was not an interactive GUI so I don't know if that's possible. Guess the CLR isn't totally blocked after all @adjan. :) - Although this apparently was for Windows XP, so not sure if it works but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The logon screen is infact a so called *"Secure Desktop"*. This means that it runs in a different desktop which does not interact with the normal user desktop (where GUI applications are run).

The only way to start a process in another desktop is to P/Invoke the [**`CreateProcess()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function, specifying the window station and desktop in the [**`STARTUPINFO`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) structure's `lpDesktop` field.

However according to [**the MSDN article about Desktops**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) *"The Winlogon desktop's security descriptor allows access to a very **restricted set** of accounts, including the LocalSystem account. **Applications generally do not carry** any of these accounts' SIDs in their tokens and **therefore cannot access the Winlogon desktop or switch to a different desktop while the Winlogon desktop is active.**"*. This meaning you will most likely not be able to run a GUI application on the Winlogon desktop.

Though I suggest you read some about [**Window Stations and Desktops**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: One could still create a CredentialProvider whose only purpose is to show a GUI. But I don't think one could start an C# app because, as far as I know, the CLR is not loaded at logon.

Comment: @adjan : A C++ app could load the CLR.

Comment: That's not what I mean, I think this is really blocked for security reasons

Comment: @adjan : Probably, yes. But do you think a C++ GUI could be run?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to start a windows application before the logon screen. There are a few ways to do this but the most practical solution in many cases would be with a [service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Modifying the logon screen itself is another matter, however, and has been made practically impossible for security reasons. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc780332%28WS.10%29.aspx) article for a more in depth explanation of windows logon.

The closest reasonable alternative to a gui on the logon screen would be [changing the background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982113/how-to-change-windows-default-log-in-out-screen-through-a-net-application), although this allows for no user interaction and cannot be done in real-time.